# Cast androidx.fragment.app.Fragment to android.app.fragment.Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, androidx

I want to cast an Android X fragment (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) to an Android native fragment (android.app.Fragment), because a library I am using does not support Android X fragments yet.

How can I achieve this?

I have already tried casting the Android X fragment to an Android native fragment, which causes a ClassCastException.

This is the code I'm currently using inside the Android X fragment. The function requires an Android native fragment. It throws a ClassCastException.

`IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this as android.app.Fragment).initiateScan();`

Comment: u can use "IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();" for using zxing inside fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

You can't. While those classes fill the same role, they are unrelated from a Java standpoint.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I expected.
I also noticed that the libary that I was trying to use was pretty outdated.

Comment: @LukasSchneider: Given the `IntentIntegrator` and `initiateScan()` symbols, I'm guessing this is a library extracted from zxing. If so, [there are many bar code scanner libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/11?sort=created).